# pygame event handling

Tags: python, event-handling, pygame

Just a noob question about python and pygame event handling.

I got the following code in a pygame tutorial:

```
while 1:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type in (QUIT, KEYDOWN):
            sys.exit()
```

...but for some reason it returns this error:

```
if event.type in (QUIT, KEYDOWN):
NameError: name 'QUIT' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 16):

I think you meant this:

```
if event.type in (pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN)
```

The tutorial probably used `from pygame import *`, and this example perfectly shows why this is a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `from pygame import *`, use:

`from pygame.locals import *`

Comment: That didn't work for me (using Python 3.4). I had to use `from pygame import *`